# How to call Internal functions ? or how to protect Withdraw and kill functions?

Tags: solidity, ether, wallets, remix, cryptography

I had some function like withdraw and self-destruct functions set as internal, but I can't call them from "Mist", then I turned them to public but I set the modifier :

```
modifier isOwner() {
if (msg.sender != owner) _; 
}
```

Then added isOwner to my functions

```
function kill() isOwner public {
    selfdestruct(beneficiary);
}
```

But when I try to call it from a subaccount (not the owner account) it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your modifier to something like

```
modifier isOwner {
  require(msg.sender == owner);
  _;
 }
```

In your case the `if` is checking if `msg.sender` is not equal to owner , if true then it continue the execution of the code.

You mentionned that you tried to set your functions as `internal` and could not call them via mist => It's normal , functions marked as `internal` can only be called inside the contract itself or contract deriving it ( as per the [official doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)) as far as I know .

Comment: Thank you Tbrunain for your reply,
So the only way to protect withdraw functions is to protect them with isOwner modifier ? if there is any other way please do share it with me

Comment: As far as I know yeah (please someone correct me if I'm wrong) , if you want to have a withdraw function and restrict its usage to only the owner , then a modifier is the way to go . Note that you can as well skip the modifier and put the `require(msg.sender == owner)` directly in the body of your withdraw function .